# Matrix of small incandescent lightbulbs - problem with buzzing

Tags: arduino, mosfet, noise, matrix, incandescent

I am prototyping a circuit for controlling matrix display of small incandescent lamps with Arduino (each lamp is 6.3V 0.3A). I designed the circuit in Yenka and built it. It is composed from 3 types of transistors: IRF640N, BD244C and TIP122. All of the resistors in my circuit are 1KΩ. I am controlling the lamps by multiplexing: one column of lamps is lighted up at each 1 millisecond. There are 20 columns of 7 lamps in my real circuit, divided in 4 groups, but only 6x3 divided in 2 groups are shown in the diagram here, connected in the same way. Everything works good, but I have small problem with the noise coming out from the electronics (it is not loud, but noticeable). At first, I though that the IRF640N transistors are causing the problem, but thanks to the suggestions I get here, I concluded that the lamps itself are the source of the noise. If I increase the pulses speed, the noise gets higher frequency. I noticed that the noice is stronger when there is a column in which all of the lamps are turned on. It also becomes louder if I try to dim the lamps intensity by adding delay between the pulses. I chose this design because it worked in Yenka. I am beginner and didn't know too much about designing circuits like this one. I would be very thankful if somebody give me directions and help me about fixing this design to eliminate the buzzing. [image]

Comment: Audible noise from a FET !  I have heard it from a coil, a ceramic cap and certainly from filaments with a Triac on dim. but never a FET Wow. Verify surge current, voltage and noise source.   Where is the low ESR cap?.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not the lightbulbs instead of the FETs?

Comment: If they are 6.3V lamps why are you powering them from 12V?

Comment: 25% duty cycle doesn't help at 1kHz if the surge R is 10% cold

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't use any other component except those shown in the diagram. I am beginner and have not used anything like that. If you think it will be helpful to reduce the noise in this circuit please suggest me where I can put it.

Comment: @marcelm maybe you are right, I am not 100% sure. The lightbulbs are on the other side on the board (behind the transistors) and that noise also can be heard from both of the sides, so maybe it comes from the lamps. Do you know how can I eliminate that noise?

Comment: @SteveG I am using 12V but that voltage is not applied on the lightbulbs constantly. Please note that I am using multiplexing to turn them on. I am using short pulses of 12V to supply them.

Comment: @220Vac we have identified the problem, which is not what you assumed. Now you have a new question. How do I fix this design?  Pls update your question on what you calculated and why you chose this design.  Otherwise they call this an XY problem Asking X when the problem is Y.  I just call it bad triage and poor assumptions but you learn from failures, so keep up the good work.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Thank you for the answer, I did not knew that the noise may be caused by the lightbulbs. I will update my question.

Comment: Or ask a new question with requirements on noise and surge current

Comment: A bit brute-force component-wise, but could you consider an inductor+capacitor per bulb and go higher in your matrix strobe frequency? A small resistor in series with each bulb to limit the inrush comes to mind too.

Comment: @winny I also think that putting capacitor to every bulb, but I am not sure if that will eliminate the problem completely. Also I don't know which type of capacitors could I use here. Probably the small ceramic ones would be too weak. I think it will be better to find some other solution with less soldering :)

Comment: @winny series R won't work with 0.1 to 1 bulb ratio unless it is an NTC which has to be faster than the bulb PTC. I have a more elegant simple solution.  Putting a cap will stress the cap with ripple current and even more stress to the FET with Ic=CdV/dt.  I wonder if the OP has any EE education?

Comment: @220vac  What response time (ms) do you need on the bulbs? And how hot are your MOSFETs?

Comment: @220vac Cap only will worsen the situation. I’m thinking a “buck” of sorts. The inductor will only be good for a few tens of us, and you will be in discontinuous conduction more in your “buck”, but perhaps it’s enough for the application.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I am not sure about the response time, there would not be any problem if something like fade effect happens during the transition from off to on. The frequency of 1KHz seems ok and there is no flickering visible. Anyway if it is needed I can increase the frequency (if it is increased the lamps have lower intensity of light). The MOSFETs or any other transistor in my circuit, are producing almost no heat, even if I touch them after long time (2-3 hours of working).

Comment: @winny sorry, I didn't understand what you wanted to say. Your idea is interesting but I think that it will be very hard to be incorporated in my design because too many components should be added.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I am not sure that we calculated the frequency in the right way. I was giving pulse with duration of 1 millisecond to every column one by one. There are 20 columns. So 20 milliseconds are needed for one cycle. So, the frequency is 50Hz.

Comment: I see. Can you increase the matrix strobe frequency and soft start each bulb instead of just one long 1 ms pulse?

Comment: @winny I can increase the frequency and feed each column with 1 microsecond long pulse. But in that case the lamps are very very dim, I don't know why. They are working good if the pulses are about 500 microseconds or higher.

Comment: @220vac You can keep your overall 1 ms/bulb but subdivide that 1 ms into a ramp up of duty cycle for the first 100 us before going full on for another 900 us. Worth a shot to try.

Comment: @winny thank you very much, I like your idea and I will try it as soon as possible. I can subdivide the pulses and try to make something like smooth fade in and even fade out transition for every pulse. I would be very happy if this problem can be solved with correcting the code only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My calculation and simulation on Falstad shows your cold surge current at 1kHz 12V 7 bulbs , low duty cycle is 80A.. or 11A per bulb. but then quickly settle to 5W peak per 1.9W bulb after the 1st pulse.    These bulbs will be BUZZing !!

This is why I use Falstad javascript sim. and became proficient in it with practice. Simple yet powerful.

Passive, IC's and logic parts are "ideal" so you must know how to add ESR, ESL and stray capacitance. Transistors are simple with hFE control , Transconductance but can approximate RdsOn =1/5beta

[image]